# Was LayoutInflater fix for RecyclerView was correct solution?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-volley, jsonobjectrequest

I was using this tutorials:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I2eYBtLWGzc

https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/06/23/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scrolling(part3)/

At first I was getting error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean)' on a null object reference 
    at pl.michalz.hideonscrollexample.adapter.parttwo.MyAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MyAdapter.java:37)
    at pl.michalz.hideonscrollexample.adapter.parttwo.MyAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MyAdapter.java:18)
```

I made changes from:

```
@Override
public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    Log.w("myApp", "onCreateViewHolder  ");
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}
```

to:

```
   View view = layoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, parent, false);
```

It fixed error, but only after few times I tired to emulate App. I had really hard time making this work, so I don't know if this is correct fix or my code is not good and it can make more error later.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private ArrayList<Receptas> receptasL = new ArrayList<>();

    public MyAdapter(Context context) {
        //layoutInflater = layoutInflater.from(context);


    }

    public void setReceptasList(ArrayList<Receptas> receptasL ){
        this.receptasL = receptasL;
        notifyItemRangeChanged(0, receptasL.size());
    }

    @Override
    public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Log.w("myApp", "onCreateViewHolder  ");
        View view = layoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Receptas receptas = receptasL.get(position);
        holder.itemTextViewPav.setText(receptas.getPav());
        holder.itemTextViewIngred_sk.setText(receptas.getIngred_sk());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return receptasL == null ? 0 : receptasL.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView itemTextViewPav, itemTextViewIngred_sk;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemTextViewPav = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemTextViewPav);
            itemTextViewIngred_sk = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemTextViewIngred_sk);
        }
    }
}
```

this is fragment class for showing RecyclerView:

```
public class PartThreeFragment extends Fragment {

    private final String url = "http://smkbaig.esy.es/get_info_test.php";
    //pridetas
    ArrayList<Receptas> receptasAList = new ArrayList<>();
    MyAdapter myAdapter;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    Receptas receptas;

    public static PartThreeFragment createInstance() {
        PartThreeFragment partThreeFragment = new PartThreeFragment();
        Log.w("myApp", ">>partThree)");
        return partThreeFragment;
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.w("myApp", "partThree>>");
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_part_three, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this.getActivity());
        volleyJson();
        return view;
    }


    public void volleyJson() {
        JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
                (Request.Method.GET, url, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {

                            JSONArray ja = response.getJSONArray("receptai");
                            for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject jsonObject = ja.getJSONObject(i);
                                receptas = new Receptas();
                                receptas.setPav(jsonObject.getString("pav"));
                                //receptas.setApras(jsonObject.getString("apras"));
                                receptas.setIngred_sk(jsonObject.getString("ingred_sk"));
                                receptasAList.add(receptas);
                                Log.w("myApp", "receptasAList.add(receptas); " + receptasAList.get(0).getPav());
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        //atliekamas po getRecceptas()
                        Log.w("myApp", "myAdapter.setReceptasList(receptasAList);");
                        myAdapter.setReceptasList(receptasAList);
//                         myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        //mTextView.setText("Response: " + response.toString());
                    }
                },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            }
                        }
                );
        requestQueue.add(jsObjRequest);
    }

}
```

There is also main activity class but I don't think it's needed.

I don't know how else ask this question if its not correct, but I would appreciate any help very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public MyAdapter(Context context) {
    //layoutInflater = layoutInflater.from(context);
}
```

You're mixing up static and instance methods here, which is your problem. At this point, the field `layoutInflater` is null. You then attempt to dereference it and call `.from()` on it (which is a static method).

This will always crash with a `NullPointerException` since `layoutInflater` is null (this line is to assign it).

Since `.from()` is a static method, you should instead be using:

```
// Note the capitalization -- I'm using the LayoutInflater class to 
// reference the static method, not the layoutInflater field.
layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
```

Comment: you can initialize `layoutInflater` as `inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);`
where `activity` is instance of `Activity` or `Context`

Comment: @AmolDesai `LayoutInflater.from(context)` is just shorthand for that. It does the same thing under the hood (see source here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/LayoutInflater.java)

Comment: Oh yes... you are right @kcoppock So both has same effect :)

Comment: i faced same problem i didn't understood what i need to do can you please help me with solution